# Openlayers 3 display in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, display, chrome, firefox

I'm experiencing some issues with displaying OSM and [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON).

With Firefox v30 I see my GeoJSON data, but OSM is invisible.
With Chrome v35 I see OSM, not my GeoJSON...

What is the explanation? (except creating "Chrofox"..)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'operation',
            source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
                //projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                url: 'emprise.geojson'}),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius:2,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'})
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({ <!--2D marche plus...2014 06 29 -->
        center:ol.proj.transform([1.22, 47.435], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom:9
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

While the answer that you have posted works, it doesn't really get to the root of the issue.

The error indicates that you are trying to load the JSON from a a location that is not on the same domain. In the OP's case, the application is not being hosted from a webserver, and is trying to load the JSON from the file system.

The real solution for this is to use a Webserver to host the files & use the HTTP protocol to access the JSON files, instead of accessing your HTML, JS & JSON files from your file system.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It was a security property of Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/.../emprise.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I have to launch Chrome using a command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-securtiy
```

See for instance Stack Overflow question *[Error message 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP in AngularJS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360700)*.

Comment: The real solution for this is to use a Webserver to host the files & use the HTTP protocol to access the html files, instead of accessing your HTML & JS files from your file system.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Could you post your comment as an answer so we have something that can be upvoted :)

Comment: @underdark: done